# PHP prepared statements and transactions in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mysqli

The classic transactions in a loop code:

```
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
foreach ($pdata as $key => $value) {
    $sql    = "INSERT INTO temp (`fund_id`) VALUES (" . $value . ")";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
}
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

Then we change to prepared statements:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
foreach ($pdata as $key => $value) {
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO temp (`fund_id`) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$mysqli->commit();
```

Questions:

1) Are these two codes identical? Am I missing something in the second code with prepared statements?

2) Is `$mysqli->commit()` the same as `$mysqli->query("COMMIT")`?

3) Do I need to add `$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");` for the prepared statements block  or the transaction will automatically start when we set `autocommit(FALSE)`?

Comment: You do not need to `START TRANSACTION` after you have turned autocommit off.  You may `$mysqli->prepare()` _before_ your loop, then  execute() it inside the `foreach` loop. There's no need to `prepare()` it on each loop iteration.

Comment: You don't need to `bind_param()` each time, either. It binds a reference to the variable, so each time you execute it will use the variable's current value.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your loop can be optimized by pulling the `prepare` and `bind_param` statements out of the loop.

```
$value = null;
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$sql  = "INSERT INTO temp (`fund_id`) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
foreach ($pdata as $value) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
$mysqli->commit();
```

You have turned off autocommit with your `autocommit(FALSE)` line and therefore don't need to use the `START TRANSACTION` statement.

Comment: short and appropriet.

Comment: Is it needed to add `rollback` statement in case of failure? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php

Comment: I believe your code is missing switch autocommit back on.